# can't find chip define in tensorflow, what templete chip<0>(index) mean?

Tags: tensorflow

I can't find chip define code in tensorflow, but it is used everywhere.
for example, `params.template chip<0>(index)`.

What does the number in `<>` mean, it seems that the number can be 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is part of the Eigen library that Tensorflow uses. The code is here:

https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/6f952374ef2b6b8786b653e3fe8b7b7b712950ef/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h?fileviewer=file-view-default